# Coinspot API with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, encryption, currency, bitcoin

I'm struggling to access the Coinspot API from PowerShell. No matter what I do I always get the "no nonce" error back from the API:

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
$key = ''
$secret = ''

$epoc_start_date = ("01/01/1970" -as [DateTime])
[int]$nonce = ((New-TimeSpan -Start $epoc_start_date -End ([DateTime]::UtcNow)).TotalSeconds -as [string])

$baseUrl = 'www.coinspot.com.au/api'
$resourcePath = '/my/orders'
$url = 'https://{0}{1}&nonce={2}' -f $baseUrl, $resourcePath, $nonce

$encoded = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
$url_bytes = $encoded.GetBytes($url)
# create hash
$hmac = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512
$hmac.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret)
$sha_result = $hmac.ComputeHash($url_bytes)
#remove dashes
$hmac_signed = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($sha_result) -replace "-";

$headers = @{
  sign = $hmac_signed
  key = $key
  'content-type' = 'application/json'
} 
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $headers
$result
```

Alternatively I have already tested this:

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
$key = ''
$secret = ''

$epoc_start_date = ("01/01/1970" -as [DateTime])
[int]$nonce = ((New-TimeSpan -Start $epoc_start_date -End ([DateTime]::UtcNow)).TotalSeconds -as [string])

$baseUrl = 'www.coinspot.com.au/api'
$resourcePath = '/my/orders'
$url = 'https://{0}{1}' -f $baseUrl, $resourcePath

$body = @{
  nonce = $nonce
}

$encoded = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
$body_bytes = $encoded.GetBytes($body)
# create hash
$hmac = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512
$hmac.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret)
$sha_result = $hmac.ComputeHash($body_bytes)
#remove dashes
$hmac_signed = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($sha_result) -replace "-";

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers @{sign = $hmac_signed ; key = $key ; 'content-type' = 'application/json' } -Body $($body | ConvertTo-Json)
```

The second gives me an `invalid` status error.
I have a feeling there's something wrong with my header.

Comment: Same here. Trying from a PHP app. As far as I know, their API has not been updated for awhile.

Answer (score 4):

Coinspot support responded:

> Apologies for this.
>
> Our current API system is way out of date and needs to be updated.
>   We know that we need to support the developers as best as we can but our current dev team are very busy with other things at the
>   moment.
>   They are aware of this and plan to update it as soon as possible, but right now there is no ETA for this.
>
> Very sorry the inconvenience.